# Operation not found: PutObject

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this code in which I use cloudfront as a delivery service (for aws sdk php):

```
    $result = $cloudfront->PutObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucketName,
        'Key'    => 'videouploads/' . $fileid,
           'Body'   => fopen($filentmpname, 'r'),
        
       
        //'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    ]);
```

Yet is causes this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Operation not found: PutObject in /var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php:248 Stack trace: #0
```

So if this is true, how else should I write up this function? Any docs that show how to use sdk with cloudfront would be useful, I've tried looking for some, but I only see example for functions that don't use cloudfront.

Comment: CloudFront doesn't have a PutObject method; S3 does.

Comment: I am using cloudfront to do that for s3. Well, I'm trying to do so.

Comment: The interface to S3 content via CloudFront is to use HTTP methods such as [GET, POST, and PUT](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-cloudfront-content-uploads-post-put-other-methods/).

Comment: I'm not sure if you entirely understand what I'm using here, or if I'm just confused with what you are saying. You can use cloudfront to access s3 buckets as a mediator, is it possible to put an object to a bucket with cloudfront using cloudfront as a mediator or no?

Comment: Yes, you can upload objects to S3 via CloudFront but the interface is HTTP, not via API calls such as PutObject. Or make the API call via S3.